# iperf bandwidth less than interface speed

Tags: linux, bonding, iperf

I used linux bonding driver to bond 2 NICs in mode 6 in client PC. 
ethtool ethX shows speed =1000 
ethtool bond0 shows speed =2000

but when i use iperf 
bandwidth of eth0 = 934Mbps
bandwidth of eth1 = 637Mbps
bandwidth of bond0 = 934Mbps

Shouldnt the bandwidth of bond0 be around 2000Mbps?

Answer (score 0):

**In short: no, bonding does not work in this manner.**

**Long story:** the linux bonding, with its various bonding scheme, is very configurable. It has no less than 7 different bonding types, each with its strong and weak points. I **strongly** suggest you to read the documentation you can found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt). However, the take away is the (except for the `round-robin` mode, which I detail below) *no bonding scheme is capable of increase the throughput of a single session*, rather they speedup *multiple* concurrent session. So your `iperf` output is perfectly normal, as it open a single session which can not be accelerated by the bonding driver.

The only expcetion to this rule is the `round-robin` mode, which transmits packet in a, well, round-robin fashion: the first one goes out from the first inteface, the second one from the second interface, and so on. This bonding mode *can* accelerate a single session by the virtue of concurrent sent packets. However it has many pitfalls, ranging from incompatible switches, out-of-order packet delivery (with relative retransmission), bad scaling over 2 interfaces, etc.

This is only a very concise summary. If you are interesting in how bonding works, you should **really** give a serious look at the documentation I provided above.

Comment: okay is there some other tool or way to show that i have an aggregated bandwidth?

Comment: but both mode rr and mode 6 has load balancing right?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experimenting with round robin - I noticed that when bonding 2 NICs it does provide a 1.6-1.7 Gb/s when using iperf (keep in mind that two machines I use to test the speed have 2 NICs each in mode 0). I did a test today with 3 NICs and got ¬900 Mb/s - the reason for this is that round robin works best with an even number of NICs. I would only use it as a backbone for server backup (on the cheap) with an NFS share...